# How to use Apex Mockery Lib for simple scenario?

Tags: apex, unit-test, mock, winter24

Was wanting to use [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) for mocking test for some time but had been too busy to try it out. I saw some devs recommending [FFLib](https://fflib.dev/) but I find it too heavy a framework for most SF envs. So looking for something that is lightweight and new, I stumbled upon [apex-mockery](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/06/introducing-apex-mockery-a-unit-test-mocking-library) that piqued my interest.

The scenario they gave was using the bakery orders and delivery. However the examples seemed to convoluted - like they created a `Bakery.cls`, `Pastry.cls`, does this mean I need to create an Apex mocking class for each Custom object I create?

If I wanted to use it for the simplest possible scenario leveraging the apex-mockery lib, how would I create/update the apex test classes to look like for say `AccountTriggerHandler` where the code will be like :

```
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static void updateAccountDescription(List<Account> accList) {
        for (Account acc : accList){
            acc.Description = "Updated via AccountTriggerHandler";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All uses of the stub API require you to write your Apex to: 1. Avoid static methods, which cannot be mocked and 2. Use some form of dependency injection (be that constructor-based like they show or using a factory that allows mocking). I think the only confusing part of their example is that I would expect the Pastry class to be an SObject, but they clearly wanted something entirely divorced from the DB layer as their example. Anyway, the point is that your Apex will have to change to allow use of mocking, whether you use this, fflib or a home spun mocking framework.

Comment: You can also check out another mocking framework -- [Amoss](https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss); the [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks) framework doesn't require to use fflib's apex-common - just that most of the examples assume fflib apex-common. Phil's point is correct; you need a factory to generate concrete and mock implementations and a way to dependency inject the mocks into the runtime.  Having bitten the bullet years ago to adopt fflib,I'd never go back. Many advantages + seamless integration w/apex mocks paid off in unit testing countless times